# Where does SQL Server restore backup from if I select Database as the source?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I restore an SQL server database from backup, I usually do it from a `.bak` file on the disk. There is also an option to restore from `Database` as a source - see this picture

[image]

Is this backup restored from the database log file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's from existing backups from databases that have been created on the server. It's essentially a list of all databases that have at least one recorded backup in the `msdb` database.

Source: [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx)

> Select the database to restore from the drop-down list. The list contains only databases that have been backed up according to the **msdb** backup history.

Comment: yes, but I'd like to know where the backup content comes from :)

Comment: @Axarydax - The backup that was made, so essentially the file system. You just won't have to manually point to the file's location.